# show array data in specific column in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I started to learn Zend in 3 days ago and got stuck. I have a table sample table like this in view.phtml

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Status</th>                   
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

and in model.php

```
public function listallemail() {
        $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter();
        $query = $db->select()
                ->from('members','email');
        return $db->fetchAll($query);
    }
```

now i have list all the email from mysql database and I want to insert only into the `<th>Email</th>` with the other column leave blank. Can anyone suggest the way for me to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the data to the controller and then pass the data to the view. Since you haven't provided any extra details I am going to guess you application structure

**controller**

```
class Default_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Abstract
{ 
    public function viewAction()            
    {                                                           

        ...
        $this->view->emaildetails = $modelObj->listallemail();
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
public function listallemail() {
        $db = $this->getDefaultAdapter();
        $query = $db->select()
                ->from('members','email');
        return $db->fetchAll($query);
    }
```

**view.phtml**

```
<thead>
    <?php foreach($this->emaildetails as $email):?>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th><?php echo $email->email ?></th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>                   
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</thead>
```